# Set color of `floatingLabelStyle` when focused on <TextField>

Tags: material-ui

[image]

With the material-ui `<TextField>`, how can I set the color of the `floatingLabel` for the focused state?

If I set the color in `floatingLabelStyle` property it assumed that color when focused of not-focused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your color in your state and then make a change to state using the `onFocus` event. Here's a quick example below.

Original app state(es6 constructor):

```
  constructor() {
        this.state = {
            floatingErrorText: 'This field is required.',      
            floatingTextColor: {color: 'blue'}
        }
    }
```

Your text field:

```
<TextField
     hintText="Project Name"
     errorText={this.state.floatingErrorText}
     floatingLabelText="Project Name"
     floatingLabelStyle={this.state.floatingTextColor}
     onFocus={this.handleFocus.bind(this)} />
```

And then to change the state use something along these lines:

```
    handleFocus(){
        this.setState({floatingTextColor: {color: 'orange'}});
    }
```

Comment: Cool.  Thanks Casey.